# R caret regression

Tags: r, r-caret

Trying to use R `caret` to train a model using `lm` linear regression:

Code is as per below:

```
modelLm <- train(x=X_train,y=Y_train, method="lm", na.action = na.omit, trControl=control)
```

But get the error:

```
Error in quantile.default(y, probs = seq(0, 1, length = cuts)) : 
            missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
```

Isn't `na.action = na.omit` supposed to ignore the missing values?

Comment: I think you have to specify the object for `na.omit`. The help page for `train` states that when using `na.omit` the argument must be named.

Comment: I see ... so something like na.action=na.omit(Y_train) ?

Comment: I think `X_train` as you shouldn't have missing values in your outcome variable, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't use a formula, the `train` calls `train.default` and `na.action` is *not* one of its arguments. `na.action` is nicely baked into the formula machinery so either use that interface or use `complete.cases` to get rid of them for `train.default`.

Max

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I used complete.cases in the end, but I don't quite understand what is meant by using a formula, care to elaborate?